# Over-extruding on small layer heights (0.06 mm), but fine above 0.15 mm?

Tags: extrusion, material

I re-assembled an i3 that used to be on a production line. It works OK when the layer height is set to 0.15 mm, but it over extrudes “A LOT” when used with a layer height like 0.06 mm.

At first I thought it was just “ANOTHER” random issue.
The same machine had:

- burnt 5 V regulator on the Arduino Mega
- burnt display (as a result of the above)
- broken extruder stepper motor (would never extrude/retract the same amount, looked like re-assembled)
- overheating A4988 drivers with Vref extremely high (above specs)
- dual Z axis motors connected in parallel, requiring bigger drivers, but still using a single A4988
- improperly assembled hotend that would clog constantly.
- screw to tighten the material (it didn't use a spring, which I prefer since it's more lenient with the material diameter)

So I kept the RAMPS 1.4, and replaced/rewired everything else. Bought a 12 V PSU, installed a new display, added four DRV8825 modded for fast-decay configuration to replace the A4988, wired the dual Z axis in series, replaced the broken motor and everything looked finally OK.

But there is one single problem that remains:
picking any layer height below 0.15 mm causes issues.

Imagine printing with a 100 % over-extrussion setting. Pieces look too wide, and you can clearly see the nozzle is "inserted" into the 3D piece because there is way too much material. I can't print small pieces because they become "bloated" and I have to stop printing after about 2 mm of height (on the Z axis) since I'm afraid the nozzle will eventually get stuck inside all the extra material.

Things I checked (other than the new components from above):

- X, Y and Z axis steps are properly calibrated
- The extruder is calibrated and it always extrudes the correct length of material
- Different steppings: 1/16 stepping when using the A4988 and 1/32 stepping with the new DRV8825.
- Different slicers. Tried Ultimaker Cura and Slic3r (the original, not the Prusa version).

Any ideas on what may be the issue? I don't know what else to try.